# Run script during system boot

Tags: linux

I'd like to run a script while system initialization. To do so I've placed my test script in standard system init directories (like described [here](http://www.slackware.com/config/init.fp)):

```
/etc/rc.d/rc.test
/etc/rc.d/rc3.d/rc.test
/etc/rc.d/init.d/rc.test
```

but none of that works. My test script just isn't run during system startup.

I'm running Slackware 4.4.14

Comment: does the script have execute permissions? objects in rc.d  folders are usually symlinks to scripts with -rwxr-xr-x permissions

Comment: Yes of course it has execute permissions set.

Comment: @rAlen any idea then?

Comment: does the script run normally when you run it manually, try putting it in /etc/init.d/ and creating symlink to it in /etc/rc.d/.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few things that must be done correctly when creating custom SysV init startup scripts.  First, they must be in the correct directory.  Typically the init scripts are placed in /etc/init.d or /etc/rc.d or /etc/init.d/rc.d, whichever directory your OS distribution uses.  Then, a symbolic link of the correct name must be made in the correct run level directory.  You can check /etc/inittab for a line with the word default or defaultinit or similar.  There is a number in there.  That will tell you the default run level when your system boots up.  For example, for most systems, the default run level is 5.  That means a symbolic link needs to go into the /etc/rc5.d, /etc/init.d/rc5.d or similar directory.  That link needs to start with a S followed by 2 digits and then whatever name you want.  For example, /etc/rc.d/rc5.d/S99rc.test would be a symbolic link to /etc/rc.d/init.d/rc.test.

The tool chkconfig does all of this for you.  Your script needs to have a certain set of comments for chkconfig to work correctly.  Check the chkconfig man page for more info.

Hope this helps.